# error: expected string-literal before ‘command’ / reusing asm volatile

Tags: c++

Im trying to run the following code, which writes to a port.

```
void write(uint8_t size, uint8_t data, uint16_t port_number){
    char command[] = "out_ %0, %1";
    command[3] = size; //outb, outw or outl
    __asm__ volatile(command: : "a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) );
}
```

i get tet the followng error message:

```
test.cpp:32:22: error: expected string-literal before ‘command’
 __asm__ volatile(command : : "a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) );
```

if i try running this line:

```
__asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1": : "a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) );
```

it compiles without problem.

Now, i know i can solve this by creating 3 versions of the write function, one for each form of 'out', but is there a better way of solving this problem without copy-pasting code?

Comment: What part about "expected string-literal" is unclear? `command` is not a string literal.

Comment: This would require changing the assembly instruction at run time. Doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `__asm__ volatile()`,  AsmTemplate, must be a string literal.

For each output sizes, you just need to call the function with the corresponding literal. You can use a branching here using if-else or switch-case:

```
void write(uint8_t size, uint8_t data, uint16_t port_number){
    char command[] = "out_ %0, %1";
    command[3] = size; //outb, outw or out
    switch(size) {
        case 'b': __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1": :"a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) ); break;
        case 'w' : __asm__ volatile("outw %0, %1": :"a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) ); break;
        case 'l' : __asm__ volatile("outl %0, %1": :"a"(data), "Nd"(port_number) ); break;
    } 
}
```

Add the cases to cover every possible 'size' values.

You can shorten each line by using a `#define` with size as its argument